# Problems with trigonometry: Circles coliding with rectangles

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, trigonometry

I've been trying to make a program where a ball bounces off of a rotating rectangle, and I had to learn some basic trigonometry for that, but the thing that I noticed when I ran it was that it was semi-inaccurate. Like whenever the ball hit the rectangle just a tad bit off center, it would either go right through or bounce off in a direction that it wasn't suppose to. To get a better visualization of my problem, I would appreciate it if you went and checked out [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/justiinRowe/apceL7rq/2/).

I think it's a problem with the math, (considering that my grade won't learn it until 10th or 11th grade), but it might be more.

---

Here's the math funcions:

```
function getNormal(a) {
    return {
        x: Math.sin(a),
        y: Math.cos(a)
    }
}

function reflect(n, v) {
    let d = 2 * dot(v, n);
    v.x -= d * n.x;
    v.y -= d * n.y;
    return v;
}

function dot(v1, v2) {
    return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that a is tangential angle (angle of surface line), in this case your normal calculation is wrong

```
    x: - Math.sin(a),
    y: Math.cos(a)

    (or for opposite normal)
    x: Math.sin(a),
    y: - Math.cos(a)
```

One more possible issue - are trigonometric functions work with radians or degrees in your language?

Comment: You missed the main problem with the OP's code. Line 102 reads `let normal = getNormal(padAngle);`  `padAngle` is `undefined` and the line should read `let normal = getNormal(pad.angle);` and I don't see any unit conversion between deg and rad so there should be no issue with the units used, apart from the scale of rotation.